# unpivot for all columns which is having null

Tags: sql, oracle, unpivot

I want all columns from table with count of null values in each column with null count.

I have query like

```
Select count(*)-count(COLA),count(*)-count(COLB),......count(*)-count(COLN) FROM TABLE;
```

I want count for each column from table having null values in row to column.

```
COLUMN NAME - COUNT
COLA        - 0
COLB        - 2
.
.
.
COLN        - 7
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**You can write like this:**

```
Select * from
(
 Select count(*)-count(COLA) Cola_cnt,count(*)-count(COLB) colb_cnt,......count(*)-count(COLN)
From your_table
)
UNPIVOT
( YOUR_COUNT
  FOR col_name in
  (Cola_cnt, colb_cnt, ...)
);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `UNPIVOT` as follows.

```
Select * from
(Select count(case when cola is null then 1 end) cola_cnt,
count(case when colb is null then 1 end) colb_cnt,
...
...
From your_table)
UNPIVOT
( CNT
  FOR col_name in
  (Cola_cnt, colb_cnt, ...)
);
```

**Demo:**

Creation of sample data:

```
SQL> CREATE TABLE YOUR_TABLE (COLA NUMBER, COLB NUMBER);

Table created.

SQL> INSERT INTO YOUR_TABLE VALUES (1,NULL);

1 row created.

SQL> INSERT INTO YOUR_TABLE VALUES (NULL,2);

1 row created.

SQL> INSERT INTO YOUR_TABLE VALUES (3,NULL);

1 row created.

SQL> SELECT * FROM YOUR_TABLE;

      COLA       COLB
---------- ----------
         1
                    2
         3
```

Query to find the desired data:

```
SQL> SELECT * FROM
  2      (   SELECT
  3              COUNT(CASE
  4                  WHEN COLA IS NULL THEN 1
  5              END) COLA_CNT,
  6              COUNT(CASE
  7                  WHEN COLB IS NULL THEN 1
  8              END) COLB_CNT
  9          FROM YOUR_TABLE
 10      ) UNPIVOT ( CNT
 11          FOR COL_NAME
 12      IN ( COLA_CNT,
 13           COLB_CNT ) );

COL_NAME        CNT
-------- ----------
COLA_CNT          1
COLB_CNT          2

SQL>
```

Cheers!!

Answer (score 0):

If you want the rows in the output to be in a specific order, you must include that order in the UNPIVOT operation. This can be done with the UNPIVOT operator, or "the old way" (how unpivoting was done before Oracle introduced the UNPIVOT operator) shown below.

Consider the standard EMP table in the SCOTT schema. It has several columns. Suppose we want to show the null count in columns EMPNO, ENAME, MGR and COMM, in that order. If you examine the table, you will see that it has 14 rows. EMPNO is primary key, so there are no nulls in that column. ENAME is NOT NULL, so obviously no nulls in that column either. MGR has exactly one null (only one person has no manager: the president of the company). COMM has many nulls (10 to be exact).

Here's how you could write the query:

```
select h.col, 
       sum(case h.col when 'EMPNO' then nvl2(e.empno, 0, 1)
                      when 'ENAME' then nvl2(e.ename, 0, 1)
                      when 'MGR'   then nvl2(e.mgr  , 0, 1)
                      when 'COMM'  then nvl2(e.comm , 0, 1)  end) as null_count
from   scott.emp e cross join 
       (select 'EMPNO' as col, 1 as ord from dual union all
        select 'ENAME'       , 2        from dual union all
        select 'MGR'         , 3        from dual union all
        select 'COMM'        , 4        from dual          ) h
group  by h.col, h.ord
order  by h.ord
;

COL   NULL_COUNT
----- ----------
EMPNO          0
ENAME          0
MGR            1
COMM          10
```

Strictly speaking, the hard-coded helper subquery I labeled **h** could have just the ORD column (then use the respective numbers instead of column names in the CASE expression in the SELECT clause), but I find this more verbose variant easier to understand.